# jQuery limit number of numbers after 

Tags: jquery, math, gstreamer

Hi I am trying to work out the best way to do the following

say I sell an item for 22.55  the GST on that is 10% which = 2.25
However it seems when I run the following

var sum = (.10 * 22.55);

it returns $2.250000002
How do I make it so it only shows the real dollars?
$2.25

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`.toFixed()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.

Example

```
var val = 24.36257;

val.toFixed(2)
```

will return 24.36

Answer (score 2):

Try the `toFixed` method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp